# Как правильно организовать многочастотные запросы node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, request, requests

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со следующим моментом: нужно делать много запросов (2-4 в секунду) на один и тот же сервер. Как такие задачи правильно организовываются? Сейчас я посылаю единичный запрос и повторяю его 2-4 раза в секунду. Правильно ли это? Логика подсказывает, что правильнее - не закрывать соединение каждый раз.

Вот сам код

```
var https = require('https');


var options = {
    hostname: 'theirSite.com',
    path: '/path',
    method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var myData = "";
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        myData = myData + chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(myData);
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});




req.end();
```

Можно ли как-то не закрывать соединение каждый раз?

Comment: Если у сервера есть websocket или Server-Sent Events, то - да. Но в вашем случае вряд ли. Да и нужно ли это вам?

Comment: @ArchDemon правильно ли я понимаю, что если сайт отдает JSON файл, то тут без вариантов и нужно каждый раз открывать и закрывать соединение?

Comment: переписать сервер/клиент на использование сокетов.

Comment: Если у вас нет доступа к серверной части, то точно без вариантов